# python crashea al usar la función "while"

Tags: python

mi problema es que la función while hace crashear python cuando creo un bucle demasiado simple, como por ejemplo

```
while wait == 1:
  time.sleep(0.01)
```

o

```
while True:
  counter += 1
```

estoy usando python 3.7. Gracias por anticipado.

edit: se que muchas personas piensan que esta es una pregunta sin esfuerzo, pero quiero que esas personas sepan que a mi si me sirvió, y probablemente a más de uno también le haya servido, así que por favor piénsenlo 2 veces antes de quitarme reputación necesaria para poder comentar y valorar otras preguntas

Comment: Depende de qué entiendas por "crashear". Lo que hacen ambos bucles es no terminar nunca, pues la condición del bucle es siempre cierta. Ya que nunca terminan y tampoco hacen nada visible, el programa parece estar "colgado". Pero si miras el consumo de CPU de tu ordenador verás que sí que están funcionand. Están consumiendo CPU sin hacer nada útil. El primero no consume tanta CPU como el segundo, pues durante el sleep la CPU puede "descansar", pero el segundo usará un core al 100%.

Comment: Además, si no interrumpes el programa de algún modo, el segundo bucle puede acabar por llenarte la memoria del computador, ya que el entero `counter` va haciéndose más y más grande, y en Python los enteros no tienen un tamaño prefijado, sino que van creciendo a medida que necesitan almacenar números mayores, mientras la memoria lo permita.

Comment: @abulafia lo que sucede exactamente es que, después de unos segundos, la ventana de python se pone de color gris en vez de negra,  a su nombre se añade "(no responde)", y windows te pregunta si quieres cerrar el proceso, porque la ventana no responde.

Comment: A cada ventana en ejecución windows le envía eventos de usuario (movimientos de ratón, etc) y la aplicación debe responder a esos eventos en un tiempo razonable. Pero no puede hacerlo en este caso porque se halla atrapada en un bucle infinito en el que la CPU está ocupada repitiendo las mismas instrucciones. Cuando windows detecta que no está procesando eventos de interfaz, es cuando la "pone gris" y windows te preguna si quieres cerrar. No es que la aplicación haya dejado de correr, sino que ha dejado de atender eventos (precisamente porque está en un bucle infinito)

Comment: @abulafia ah ok, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya descubrí como arreglarlo, lo único que hay que hacer es añadir una función que checkee pygame.key.get_pressed, pygame.mouse.get_pressed, o cualquier otra "entrada de información". Algo parecido a esto:

```py
while True:
    checkEvents() # función que checkee eventos
    #lo que tengas que hacer

    for i in range(1000) * 15 # suponiendo que tienes un "for" muy largo...
       checkEvents()
       #lo que tengas que hacer
```

Answer (score 1):

Para probar exactamente tu cuestión, he probado ambos que por lógica deben funcionar:

```
import time
wait = 1
while wait == 1:
  time.sleep(0.01)
  print("loop")
```

y

```
counter = 0
while True:
  counter += 1
  print(counter)
```

**Ambos funcionan y dan output**.

¿Podríamos ver el código completo?

Comment: hola maduranma, puedes tomar ese como el código completo, los he probado y el problema sucede igual, Pero el crasheo solo sucede si el bucle el muy pequeño (como tus ejemplos). Supongo que el problema se podria deber a los pocos recursos de mi computadora, aunque supongo que deberian sobrar para hacer un time.sleep()